# Throws error when i run it from different computer

Tags: java, sql

```
Statement stmt = db.conn.createStatement();    
String sql = "insert into nameList "+ "values ('"+name+"','"+id+"')";           
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

I use this codes to take data from a database, but it throws error when i run it from another computer, where the database is also given.

Comment: What error? -.-

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I will use my psychic powers to solve this one. It's a permissions issue. Given the information we've got, it's as good a guess as any.

Comment: Quick tip: try setting your username to something other than the randomly generated one if you plan to get involved more with the SO community or at least have higher chances at getting help :) A lot of the people that do not personalize their account are just hit-and-runners and I'd say, often avoided because they don't plan to give back to the community in any way once someone else has solved their issue(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Prepared Statement instead of Statement, i also faced problem but a friend of mine in stackOVERFLOW help me to sort this out. I am new to this website, so you can find my questions easily , as they are very few. Check those , those may help you.